# can not debug windows phone 8.1 - specified communication resource (port) is already in use

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2017

I have installed VS2015 (Enterprise) and VS2017 (Enterprise) side by side.
Now I can not deploy and debug windows phone 8.1 silverlight app on a device. I get the error "A specified communication resource (port) is already in use by another application". Launching AgHoste.exe failed!
It works fine on my laptop (only VS2015 installed).

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Chances are you need to quit both VS2015 and VS2017, if that fails, perhaps a reboot of the machine will help

Comment: @Michael, We can run this app at a time one device only from visual studio, I mean that not debug the same device on two or more visual studio IDEs. Just close all VS, open it using one VS IDE, view the result：http://blog.masterdevs.com/a-specified-communication-resource-port-is-already-in-use-by-another-application/

Comment: @t0mm13b, I have rebooted the computer several times and still get the same error.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, Only VS2015 is open. Explicit deploy the App does not solve the problem.

Comment: @t0mm13b, not debug your app, just run it using "start without debugging", how about the result? Is it related to the device you will deploy?